# How to stretch Image in OSX app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I want to stretch an Image to fit a view. In iOS I have used this function.

`[myImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:13];`

This stretches the image correctly and doesn't distort its edges and corners. In OSX app development I am using NSImage and NSImageView. Is there any OSX equivalent way of achieving this? If it can be achieved through storyBoards then it will be wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply set the `imageScaling`. [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSImageView/imageScaling) gives you the following options;

1. NSImageScaleProportionallyDown
2. NSImageScaleAxesIndependently
3. NSImageScaleNone
4. NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown

If you just want to stretch the image to fit the NSImageView you can do something like this.

**Swift**

```
let imageView = ...
imageView.imageScaling = .ImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSImageView *imageView = ...;
[imageView setImageScaling: NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown];
```

Comment: Which scaling properties did you use? "ScaleAxesIndependently" is equal to saying "stretch to fit" and distorts the image to fill the NSImageView. Updated the code to use non-distorting properties.